# How to uninstall eclipse che completely on mac osx?

Tags: eclipse, macos, docker

How to uninstall eclipse che completely on mac osx?

Used mac osx installer to install binary. Seems che is always running on 8080 even killed the process and stopped docker.

https://eclipse.org/che/

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find the better way for uninstall on Mac but you can stop the Tomcat embedded in Eclipse Che. 
The path is /Applications/EclipseChe3.12.5.2.app/Contents/Resources/eclipse-che/tomcat/bin

Next step is stop the Tomcat instance and finally delete the folder EclipseChe3.12.5.2.app because that's my Eclipse Che version.

So, I hope this is helpfully for you

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Docker the process is different.

Get the list of active instance in Docker by running the following command in Terminal: `docker ps`

Then you can stop the running instance by running in `docker stop XXX` where XXX is the name of the running container instance. You may have more than one container instance to stop.

Then you can remove it by running `docker rm XXX` and then you can list images that are present on your system by running `docker images`
If you want to completely remove Che, then pickup for the images list the ones that are related to che and remove them by running the following command: docker mi image_name

Last command to stop docker on your mac will be `docker-machin stop environment_name`. If you do not know the name of the running environment you can figure it out by running `docker-machine ls`